# TypeError: $.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in JavaScript.

```
$scope.getBanksyUrl = (data) => {
    $.get('banksyurlservlet', function(data) {
        //return the url here
    });
};
```

But when I invoke this function, I see in my JS console:

```
TypeError: $.get is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.getBanksyUrl (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/js/admin/campaignModule.js:136:8)
    at fn (eval at compile (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.5.8/angular.js:25885:17)
    at Scope.$eval (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.5.8/angular.js:17682:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.5.8/angular.js:17782:25)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.5.8/angular.js:25890:23)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.5.8/angular.js:3497:11)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.5.8/angular.js:3485:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.wrapped (http://admin.gearlaunch-dev.com:8080/jspm_packages/github/getsentry/raven-js@3.3.0/dist/raven.js:351:29) undefined
```

What am I currently doing wrong?

Comment: Do you include jquery*.js in you html e.g. `<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`?

Comment: again - Do you include jquery*.js in your **html**

Comment: I added it to the top of my tpl.html, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: @ScaryWombat Just pasted the error above at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. `$` could be overridden by some other library.

Also, it's better to use `angularJs $HTTP service`. E.g.:

    `$http.get("welcome.htm").then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });`

You can read more [here, in AngularJs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).